# Add audio to Map on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mapkit

I have a map right now with several points on it that are quite close to each other. Right now when a user taps the annotation a little pop up occurs with the location name on it. How could I have it so that a piece of audio about that location plays?

I'm not too fussed about pause buttons etc yet, right now I want to know how I'd implement audio into this!

Comment: The answer to use AVSpeechSynthesizer is fine but if you intend to play _pre-recorded_ audio, you can use the AVAudioPlayer class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Some random text that you want to be spoken"];
[utterance setRate:0.7];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

http://jonathanfield.me/avspeechsynthesizer-ios-text-speech-ios-7/

[Text to speech conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195902/text-to-speech-conversion/22195989#22195989)

UPDATE:

Add delegate to your MKMapView. For example it could be `self`

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

(self should confirm to MKMapViewDelegate). And implement delegate's method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)anView
{
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:anView.annotation.title];
    [utterance setRate:0.7];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: This is great! How would I go about adding it to annotations? For example my annotation is: `newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Royal Observatory" andCoordinate:twoLocation];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];`

Comment: thank you for the update and also for helping me! I've done this and it works but as soon as I run the app it plays the voice, whereas I want it so it only occurs when clicked. Not sure why it does it when it's run. Also so far I can only get it to say "some title" because it doesn't like the `[AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:anView.title]` specifically the `title` part. It says the property not found on object of type MKAnnotationView

Comment: I have fixed problem with `title` - check updated answer. But I do not know why it plays before clicking. Are you sure you do not have something like `newAnnotation.selected = YES` at the start?

Comment: YES that's perfect thank you! ONE last nitpicky question - instead of title say I want it to be a little description about the place. So I add `NSString *desc;` to the MapViewAnnotation file and add it everywhere else (i use initWithDesc, is that right?) but when I change that `anView.annotation.title` to say `desc` instead of `title` it does not work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only guess that you need to change `anView.annotation.title` to `((MapViewAnnotation *)anView).desc`. If it will not help please open new question (do not forget to paste problem code!). It is a bad practice to mix several questions in one thread. If you will post a new question's link here I will try to help you in a new thread. And please do not forget to accept my answer if it was useful!

Comment: THanks for all your help on this! I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441216/using-avspeechsynthesizer-to-read-a-description-of-location-on-a-map