# Using AVSpeechSynthesizer to read a description of location on a Map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, avspeechsynthesizer

My map has 4 or 5 points close to each other and right now using AVSpeechSynthesizer I've got it so that it will say the name of the location (which is also displayed in a little bubble).

I want it to still show that bubble but when clicked I want it to say a description of that place that I would have specified. This is my code at the moment:

**MapViewAnnotation.h**

```
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *desc;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *desc;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d initWithDesc:(NSString *)dsc;
```

**MapViewAnnotation.m**

```
@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate, desc;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d initWithDesc:(NSString *)dsc {
[super init];
title = ttl;
coordinate = c2d;
    desc = dsc;
    return self;
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView *mapView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Set some coordinates for our position : Cutty Sark
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double) 51.482997;
    location.longitude = (double) -0.010072;

    // Royal Observatory
    CLLocationCoordinate2D twoLocation;
    twoLocation.latitude = (double) 51.477805;
    twoLocation.longitude = (double) -0.001430;

    //Royal Naval College
    CLLocationCoordinate2D threeLocation;
    threeLocation.latitude = (double) 51.483344;
    threeLocation.longitude = (double) -0.006799;

    //Queen's House
    CLLocationCoordinate2D fourLocation;
    fourLocation.latitude = (double) 51.481383;
    fourLocation.longitude = (double) -0.003722;

    //National Maritime Museum
    CLLocationCoordinate2D fiveLocation;
    fiveLocation.latitude = (double) 51.481050;
    fiveLocation.longitude = (double) -0.005578;


    // Add Cutty Sark annotation to MapView
    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cutty Sark" andCoordinate:location initWithDesc:@"Description about Cutty Sark"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [newAnnotation release];


    // Add Royal Observatory annotation to MapView
    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Royal Observatory" andCoordinate:twoLocation initWithDesc:@"Description about Cutty Sark"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];

    // Add Royal Naval College annotation to MapView
    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Royal Naval College" andCoordinate:threeLocation initWithDesc:@"Description about Cutty Sark"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];

    // Add Queen's House annotation to MapView
    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Queen's House" andCoordinate:fourLocation initWithDesc:@"Description about Cutty Sark"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];

    // Add National Maritime Museum annotation to MapView
    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"National Maritime Museum" andCoordinate:fiveLocation initWithDesc:@"Description about Cutty Sark"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];


}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)anView
{
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:((MapViewAnnotation *)anView).desc];
    [utterance setRate:0.5];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}


// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it (1500 range)
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
    //[mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Here is the NSLog:

[image]

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%@ %@", anView, ((MapViewAnnotation *)anView).desc);`  to method  `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)anView` and post log output? This is needed to localize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method, the `anView` parameter is the `MKAnnotationView`.

That is, `anView` is the *view* (`MKAnnotationView` or `MKPinAnnotationView` class) object of the annotation.

It is not the *model* (your `MapViewAnnotation` class) object of the annotation.

To refer to the  annotation model instance that the view is for, use the view's `annotation` property and cast it to your class:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)anView
{
    //Get a reference to the annotation this view is for...
    id<MKAnnotation> annSelected = anView.annotation;

    //Before casting, make sure this annotation is our custom type
    //(and not some other type like MKUserLocation)...
    if ([annSelected isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
    {
        MapViewAnnotation *mva = (MapViewAnnotation *)annSelected;

        AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = 
            [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:mva.desc];

        [utterance setRate:0.5];
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and also thank you for the great explanation! I walked into iOS hating it and terrified but I'm slowly learning - thanks again.