# Want to do textToSpeak method when a specific annotation pin is clicked. Whats the correct way?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;
@property ( nonatomic, copy)NSString * subtitle;
- (void)textToSpeak:(NSString *  )theString;

@end
```

`#import "Annotation.h"`
`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

`@implementation Annotation`

```
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

-(void)textToSpeak:(NSString *)theString{


AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:theString   ];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US" ];
utterance.rate = 0.70*AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate;

AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth= [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance ];



}@end
```

// I have a simple annotation class. In my ViewController.m I can get all the pins to show up as I want them. The problem is that I want to perform an action each time a specific pin is clicked. An action such as speaking the name of the title. Any guidance will be useful. Thanks!!

Comment: You can use the AVSpeechSynthesizer class.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441216/using-avspeechsynthesizer-to-read-a-description-of-location-on-a-map for an example.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am able to do that: the problem is that I want to do that when a specific annotation pin is clicked.  When i do it now it crashes, because it does the speech as soon as the mapView is loaded as opposed to only when a specific annotation pin is clicked.

Comment: Show the code you have now that crashes and the exact crash message.

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D inOutLocation;
    inOutLocation.latitude = in_lat;
    inOutLocation.longitude = in_lon;
    
    Annotation * myAnnotation2 = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    myAnnotation2.coordinate = inOutLocation;
    myAnnotation2.title = @"In N OUT";
    myAnnotation2.subtitle = @"Thats what our hamburgers all about";
    [myAnnotation2 textToSpeak:@"Thats the burgers i love"];
 [myLocations addObject:myAnnotation2  ]

Comment: This is the error :2014-05-14 19:10:14.175 UNLVmap[1637:4b03] 19:10:14.174 ERROR:     AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:88: GetProperty_DefaultToZero: AudioSessionGetProperty ('disa') failed with error: '?ytp'

Comment: Don't call textToSpeak when you create the annotation.  Call it in didSelectAnnotationView.  Look at the linked example.