# Play audio for directions using MapKit inside an ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am developing an ios app that has MKMapView embedded. And the app shows route from current location to the destination. I have managed to do this.

Can we play audio for step by step route inside our own app? Does apple provide us some libraries so that our app can play the instructions? How can this be done more efficiently

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426464/add-audio-to-map-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are steps you can follow to achieve this.

1. Store Coordinates of all the step endpoints.
2. Store direction instructions of individual step.
3. Inside the method,

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;

compare the distance of your current location with the current step start coordinates. And if the distance is within some limit, say 50 meters, you can play the audio.

I am not sure Mapkit provides you the coordinates of individual step coordinates. However, Google map sdk for iOS does provide all the coordinates of each route points.

Comment: Thanks. I went with using Google maps. Apple indeed does not provide the coordinates of each step endpoints.

Comment: Drill down into the polylines to get all coordinates.